# C# Rendering Performance Difference

Tags: c#, performance, rendering

I am using Dynamic Data Display to draw some plots.

It provides a class called MarkerPointsGraph to render markers to the screen. The OnRender method is called during Render and this in turn calls the appropriate marker's (Circle, Triangle, etc.) render method.

```
    protected override void OnRenderCore(DrawingContext dc, RenderState state)
    {
        if (DataSource == null) return;
        if (Marker == null) return;

        var transform = Plotter2D.Viewport.Transform;

        DataRect bounds = DataRect.Empty;
        using (IPointEnumerator enumerator = DataSource.GetEnumerator(GetContext()))
        {
            Point point = new Point();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                enumerator.GetCurrent(ref point);
                enumerator.ApplyMappings(Marker);

                //Point screenPoint = point.Transform(state.Visible, state.Output);
                Point screenPoint = point.DataToScreen(transform);

                bounds = DataRect.Union(bounds, point);
                Marker.Render(dc, screenPoint);
            }
        }

        Viewport2D.SetContentBounds(this, bounds);
    }

/// <summary>Renders circle around each point of graph</summary>
public class CirclePointMarker : ShapePointMarker {

    public override void Render(DrawingContext dc, Point screenPoint) {
        dc.DrawEllipse(Fill, Pen, screenPoint, Size / 2, Size / 2);
    }
}
```

Now, my calling code is as below.

```
        plotter.AddLineGraph(
            data.Data,
            new Pen
            {
                Brush = Brushes.Violet,
                DashStyle = DashStyles.DashDot,
                Thickness = 3
            },
            GetMarker(data),
            new StandardDescription(data.Title));
```

The main difference I noticed in performance is in the methods below.

Referring to data from the ChartData class

```
private ShapePointMarker GetMarker(ChartData data)
    {
        ShapePointMarker marker = null;

        switch (data.MarkerShape)
        {
            case Shapes.Circle:
                marker = new CirclePointMarker();
                break;

            case Shapes.Triangle:
                marker = new TrianglePointMarker();
                break;

            case Shapes.None:
            default:
                marker = null;
                break;
        }

        if (marker != null)
        {
            //Referring to stuff here.
            marker.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(data.MarkerColor);
            marker.Size = data.MarkerSize;
        }

        return marker;
    }
```

Hardcoding the data in place of the reference.

```
private ShapePointMarker GetMarker(ChartData data)
    {
        ShapePointMarker marker = null;

        switch (data.MarkerShape)
        {
            case Shapes.Circle:
                marker = new CirclePointMarker();
                break;

            case Shapes.Triangle:
                marker = new TrianglePointMarker();
                break;

            case Shapes.None:
            default:
                marker = null;
                break;
        }

        if (marker != null)
        {
            //Hard coding stuff here.
            marker.Fill = Brushes.Red;
            marker.Size = 5;
        }

        return marker;
    }
```

I see an improvement of nearly 100x in the render times merely by changing the reference based data in the GetMarker method to a hard coded value.

What behaviour of C# causes this difference?

EDIT: The MarkerPointsGraph does not create an object of Marker for each point. It merely calls the render method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try freezing your Brush:

```
if (marker != null)
{
    Brush b = new SolidColorBrush(data.MarkerColor);
    b.Freeze();  
    marker.Fill = b;  
    marker.Size = data.MarkerSize;  
}
```

`Brushes.Red` is already Frozen that might be why you see the performance increase.

Comment: Have also spent some time reading up on freezable objects now. :D

Comment: No problem, I ran into the same thing when I first started doing more performance intensive rendering. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing too much more about your setup, your issue likely lies in the fact that you are creating a `SolidColorBrush` in a relatively tight loop (and not disposing them, but that's another issue).  That object has a fair amount of overhead associated with creating a new one, whereas using `Brushes.Red` uses the same instance and so doesn't have the same issues.  If you were to create your own brush once I don't think you'd see the same problems.